# AWS IAM policy. Allow user to delete only the ec2 instances that they created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, policy

How can i change the policy to allow user to delete only the ec2 instances that they created? I got an example from the document here. Is creating tags, and tagging it to my instances, the only way to do it? Thanks!

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ec2:StartInstances",
        "ec2:StopInstances",      
        "ec2:RebootInstances",
        "ec2:TerminateInstances"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:ResourceTag/critical":"true"
        }
      },
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:your_region:your_account_ID:instance/*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly point out, a way to achieve this is by using tags at the EC2 instance-level.

The official documentation explains this approach: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_tags.html

Quoting that document:

> You can attach this policy to the IAM users in your account. If a user named `richard-roe` attempts to start an Amazon EC2 instance, the instance must be tagged `Owner=richard-roe` or `owner=richard-roe`. Otherwise he will be denied access.

So you can force the creation of the tag with a specific value on new instances, and then also limit the access levels of the user to start/stop/terminate them:

```json
{
  "Sid": "AllowRunInstancesWithRestrictions",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "ec2:RunInstances",
    "ec2:CreateVolume",
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
    "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
  ],
  "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "aws:RequestTag/Owner": "${aws:username}"
    },
    "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
      "aws:TagKeys": [
        "Owner"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "Sid": "AllowControlAndTerminateInstancesWithRestrictions",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "ec2:StartInstances",
    "ec2:StopInstances",
    "ec2:RebootInstances",
    "ec2:TerminateInstances",
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
    "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
  ],
  "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "aws:ResourceTag/Owner": "${aws:username}"
    }
  }
}
```

This way you can decide on your AWS account which unique `Owner` tags exist, and then limit permissions for IAM users based on the values of your choice.  Coupled with a policy for only allowing to tag instances on creation, the specific IAM user will only be able to apply those tags on new instances they create.

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/supported-iam-actions-tagging.html:

> The following example demonstrates a policy that allows users to launch instances and apply any tags to instances and volumes during launch. Users are not permitted to tag any existing resources (they cannot call the ec2:CreateTags action directly).

```json
{
  "Sid": "AllowCreateTagsOnlyLaunching",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "ec2:CreateTags"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
    "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
  ],
  "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "ec2:CreateAction": [
        "RunInstances",
        "CreateVolume",
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It won't protect you in case another part of your system uses the same `Owner` tag for unrelated instances, but with good internal tooling you could avoid that easily.